# Javascript - where can i get UTC timezone database

Tags: javascript, database, timezone

I want to create a timezone combobox like below.

Where can i get timezone database?

**I need 2 information:** 

   1. timezone's name ( eg: (UTC+7:00) Bangkog, Hanoi, Jakarta)

   2. timezone's abbreviation ( eg: ICT, Z,PET, etc)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are after creating a list of timezones. It might be better to use the momentJS timezone library.

There are many many timezones so you may want to play with the data a bit

https://jsfiddle.net/netey6qu/

```
moment.tz.names().forEach(function(timezone){
  moment.tz(timezone).format('Z');
}
```

Comment: For me, it's not user frendly. I want to give to user timezones like above image

Comment: Yup, all you have to do is put in the timezones you want displayed in an array and then look up the GMT offset to be displayed.
If your list of timezones you want to display is small, you might be better off hardcoding the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the timezone API at :

https://timezonedb.com/
https://timezonedb.com/api

You can easily access that rest API using cUrl in PHP like so :

```
    <?php
        $url        = "http://api.timezonedb.com/v2/list-time-zone";
        $api_key    = "EHAI29SVZ652";
        $query      = "format=json&key=$api_key";
        $ch         = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url . "?" . $query);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        echo print_r($response, 1);
    ?>
```